# How to populate unordered list from array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, cordova

I'm currently creating an app with Phonegap. I want to loop through a form of array to create an unordered list with this format where url and title are the stored values:

```
<li><a href="[url]">[title]</a></li>
```

I'm a bit new with this way of developing apps, and I'm not really sure the best way to store this data in the root of my app. I guess I could've made an JS array, but I want to keep it saved in a seperate file. I therefore made a json file:

```
{
  "title": "thisistheurl.com",
  "title": "thisistheurl.com"
}
```

How am I able to create this list based on my data from my local json file? I tried this one without any luck:

```
$.getJSON( "links.json", function( data ) {
                  var items = [];
                  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    $("linkList").append( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
                  });
});
```

Comment: `key` is `'title'` and `val` is `'thisistheurl.com'`. Switch those around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things you need to change in:

```
   $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    $("linkList").append( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
                  });
```

At first, there is no element called `linkList`, may be you wanted to append the elements in `ul` with class `.linkList` or Id `#linkList`.

Another one, Inside `$.each` key represents `title` and value represents `the url`. But you have assigned it wrongly.

```
      $("linkList").append( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
```

It should be

```
      $("selector").append( "<li id='" + val+ "'>" + key+ "</li>" );
```

And i dont see any `a` tag here. You may need to add `a` tag as well.

Also note that you can't have duplicate keys `title` in an object. In that case you may need to go with an array of objects.

```
[{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "link" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "link" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "link" : "thisistheurl.com"
}]
```

DEMO:

```js
   
var data = [{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "link" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "link" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "link" : "thisistheurl.com"
}];  

 $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
 var $li = $("<li><a href='"+val.link+"'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");      
 $("#linkList").append($li);            
 });
```

```css
ul#linkList  {
border: 1px solid black;  
}
#linkList li a:link {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<ul id="linkList"></ul>
```

Comment: Does not really contains a solution for Json, but works. For people searching for Json, replace the array with `$.getJSON( "listoflinks.json", function( data ) { REST OF JS CODE GOES HERE }`.

Comment: yes, since ajax call will fail here, I've used an array

Comment: I thought so. Unfortunately my solution doesn't work well with Jquery mobile. The CSS style isn't added to the appended list items. Only if I add them manually inside the `<ul id="linkList" data-role="listview"></ul>`. Do you have any idea what might be wrong? The css-styles are added before JS is run?

Comment: Nope styles will apply to all dynamically craeted elements. In that code, linkList is not closed with double quotes. may be that's the error?

Comment: Updated answer with styles :) Hope now it deserves an upvote ;)

Comment: No, just a type as I wrote it manually. And as I said..it works if I add the `<li>`'s manually. Remember that JQuery mobile probably adds CSS through JS, and the plugin already contains the styles. So no need to add them myself.